# Creating a Java Game Pig

Tags: java, oop, object

I am in the process of creating the java game PIG, each player gets to roll a dice and each turn is added to a score and the first player to get 100 is the winner, the players can choose to roll the dice or hold, if the player rolls and land a 1 their turn is over and all points go to 0, if a player chooses to hold all points gained during the turn are added to her school.

I do however have some issues that i cannot work out, when a user rolls a 1 and their turn would be over and no points given, instead the program gives no output and does not carry on playing (going into an infinite loop??).

edit:
i have since been able to solve the previous issues however i now only get an infinite loop when the program is ran and i do not understand why, Also does anyone know how to make the game replayable after a game has ended?

below is my new code:

```
//Callum Fawcett
//Game of Pig
//Create: 20/02/2019
//Version 0.1

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class game2
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int playerScores = 0;
      int playerTotal = 0;
      int computerScores = 0;
      int computerTotal = 0;
      int dice;
      boolean gameOver = false;
      boolean turnOver = false;
      char repeat;
      String input;   
      Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);

  Random rand = new Random();

  System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

  while (gameOver == false)
  {    
     do
     {
        dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("You rolled: " + dice);
        if (dice == 1)
        {
           playerScores = 0;
           System.out.print("You lose your turn! ");
           System.out.println("Your total is " + playerTotal);
           turnOver = true;
        }
        else
        {
           playerScores += dice;
           System.out.print("Your turn score is " +
                            playerScores);
           System.out.println(" If you hold you will have " +
                              playerScores + " points.");
           System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll " +
                              "again, 'h' to hold.");
           input = keyboard.nextLine();
           repeat = input.charAt(0);

           if (repeat == 'h')

              break;                               
        }
     } while(turnOver == false || dice != 1);
        playerTotal += playerScores;
        System.out.println("Your score is " +
                           playerTotal);   
        playerScores = 0;
     if (playerTotal >= 100)
     {
        System.out.println("YOU WIN!");
        gameOver = true;

     } 

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("It is the computer's turn.");
     do
     {
        dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("The computer rolled: " +
                           dice);
        if(dice == 1)
        {
           computerScores = 0;
           System.out.print("The computer lost its turn!");
           System.out.print(" Computer total is " + 
                            computerTotal);
           turnOver = false;

        }
        else
        {
           computerScores += dice;
           if(computerScores >= 20 || (computerTotal +
              computerScores) >= 100)
              System.out.println("The computer holds");
              turnOver = false;
        }
     } while (dice != 1 || computerScores < 20);

        computerTotal += computerScores;
        System.out.println("The computer's score is " +
                           computerTotal + "\n");
        computerScores = 0;
     if (computerTotal >= 100)
     {
        System.out.println("THE COMPUTER WINS!");
        gameOver = true;

     }
     if(keyboard!=null)
     keyboard.close();

   }
 }
}
```

this is an output i get :

```
TheRealFawcett:lab5 therealfawcett$ java game2
Welcome to the game of Pig!

You rolled: 6
Your turn score is 6 If you hold you will have 6 points.
Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.
r
You rolled: 4
Your turn score is 10 If you hold you will have 10 points.
Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.
r
You rolled: 1
You lose your turn! Your total is 0
Your score is 0

It is the computer's turn.
The computer rolled: 2
The computer rolled: 2
The computer rolled: 1
The computer lost its turn! Computer total is 0The computer's score is 
0

You rolled: 2
Your turn score is 2 If you hold you will have 2 points.
Enter 'r' to roll again, 'h' to hold.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner 
closed
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1781)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1649)
at game2.main(game2.java:50)
TheRealFawcett:lab5 therealfawcett$
```

Comment: `while(playerTotal < 100);` is an infinite loop, since you are not incrementing the value there.

Comment: @racraman how would i change it from an infinite loop then?

Comment: I think you can just delete that line (and those others like it).  You've already set turnover=true in that if block, so that would exit the containing `do { ... } while(turnOver == false || dice != 1);`   (so the dice != 1 is also redundant there).   It would probably also pay you to refactor so the commonalities between player and computer are in a single block of code (ie a new method), since at present you have to change identical lines in both.

Comment: I deleted all those type of lines and when 'r' is pressed to rold again it give a load of outputs then closes the game

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to reset `turnover = false` before both the player's and computer's turn (common code ;)  ), otherwise once set it'll  keep happening.

Comment: Apologies that last comment was false it gives all the computers answers, which is fine however once the computers turn is finished the game goes into another infinite loop. also is there a way of codinging something to restart the game?

Comment: Sorry, but I think at this point have a shot at refactoring as I mentioned earlier, and debugging.  One thing is to format your code - especially indentation;  Your IDE should be able to do that for you, and that often helps with finding problems - eg, I suspect your "if (keyboard != null)" at the end should be moved a loop or two out.   Good luck, and if still having issues after refactoring, post again :)

Comment: One last thing : `while (dice != 1 || computerScores < 20);` should probably use `&&` rather than `||`.  Get used to reading your code as much like English as possible, so "Loop while the dice roll isn't 1 AND the computer's score is still less than 20".

Comment: Is there some sample output from all these print lines?

Comment: @Jai what do you mean??

Comment: @CallumFawcett Your codes have so much `println()`, surely you could extract some out so that we know where exactly the looping occurred.

Comment: @Jai i have added the full output i get

Comment: There is no infinite loop, you called `keyboard.close();` where the only condition for it to execute is that the `Scanner` is not null. Therefore your program will always run *one* time without exception.

Comment: @jai so how would i now get it to repeat the the game?

Comment: Your program has been built to run one time, as far as I can see. If you want the player to be able to play a new game, then you need to prompt the user to see if they would like to do so. Then all your codes would be within another loop. At this point I would recommend splitting into methods - your current method is getting too complicated.